# Oracle Apex 5.1 Interactive Report in Tab Container; how to set current tab in URL

Tags: oracle, tabs, containers, apex

I'm linking to an interactive report using apex_page.get_url. I have multiple IR's on the page so I am using the syntax described [here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-5.1/HTMDB/linking-to-interactive-reports.htm#HTMDB30108) to specify which report and set a report filter. This is all working. However, the reports are in a Tab Container region, and on page load the first Tab is always selected. Is it possible to create a URL that causes the correct Tab to be selected?

Answer (score 0):

Give all the reports a static id. Created a new hidden item on the target page called PXX_SHOW_TAB. Set this to the "name" of the tab you want to show by passing the name in the URL. You can find the name by inspecting in browser. The Anchor element will have a href like "#SR_TAB_STATIC_ID". Add a "on page load" DR that executes JS:

```
sessionStorage.setItem('.<APP_ID>.<PAGE_ID>.activeTab', '#' + $v('PXX_SHOW_TAB'));
```

I have "remember active tab" selected for the tabs container:
[Container Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNfmG.png)